# Turn multidimensional c++ std::array into multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, c++17, stdarray

I have a multidimensional c++ `std::array` (i don't know how many dimensions does it have), and i want to turn it into a multidimensional vector. I thought at a function that returns a vector if a `std::array` is passed, else throws error. I am pretty sure the fastest way to do this is by using function recursion, but i actually don't know how to implement this. 
Just to be clear, my input array could be something with 1D like this: `[1,2,3]`; but also something with much more dimensions like this:

```
[
  [
    [1,2,3]
    [4,5,6]
  ],
  [
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how many dimensions, or you don't know how many elements? Only with templates could it be "dimensions"

Comment: @Jeffrey hi, i mean i don't know how many dimensions my input `std::array` has. I am quite sure templates are a must for this task...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool IsArray = false;

template<typename T, std::size_t S>
inline constexpr bool IsArray<std::array<T, S>> = true;

template<typename T>
auto ToVector(const T& arr) {
    static_assert(IsArray<T>, "Expected an std::array!");

    if constexpr (IsArray<typename T::value_type>) {
        using U = decltype(ToVector(arr.front()));
        std::vector<U> vector{};
        vector.reserve(arr.size());
        std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(vector), [](const auto& a) { return ToVector(a);});
        return vector;
    }
    else {
        return std::vector<typename T::value_type>{ arr.begin(), arr.end() };
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 3>, 2> arr{
        std::array < std::array<int, 4>, 3 > {
            std::array<int, 4>{1,2,3,4},
            std::array<int, 4>{4,5,6,7},
            std::array<int, 4>{8,9,10,11},
        },
        std::array < std::array<int, 4>, 3 > {
            std::array<int, 4>{12,13,14,15},
            std::array<int, 4>{16,17,18,19},
            std::array<int, 4>{20,21,22,23},
        },
    };

    const auto vector = ToVector(arr);
}
```

Note, that despite the name `std::is_array` returns false for `std::array`, so we needa `IsArray` helper.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. Won't `IsArray` return `true` for classic C arrays?

Comment: @Giuppox no, it only works for `std::array`.

Comment: do you think it is possible to make this work for classic C arrays too?